# readability of long int v. long

Tags: c++, c

Which is more clear to someone reading code? "long" or "long int". "long int" is more descriptive, but "long" is more succinct.

Comment: Did you ever notice that `short` is one character longer than `long`?

Comment: I always use `int` because it's even shorter ;)

Comment: @chris Exactly, which means it runs faster -- that's why I always use single character variable names as well

Comment: This came from a conversation I had the other day where I suggested using a "long" and a PhD candidate said "long WHAT?" and I said "oh, long int" and he said "ooh"

Comment: @John: depends on your architecture

Comment: @chris: not according to the standard.  they are separate and distinct types.  depending on your architecture they might be the same size, but this is just a coincidence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Long int" is more descriptive, but "long" is more succinct.

Comment: You quoted the second sentence of the question

Comment: Tempted to upvote this for copying text verbatim out of the question...

Comment: Can you elaborate please thanks

Comment: @Michael: not my fault if there's an answer in the question. Furthermore, I find it pretty reasonable.

Comment: @turdfurguson It sounds like you're saying you'd prefer he be more descriptive rather than succinct -- go with "long int" :)

Answer (score 0):

They are the same thing. long is just a short hand for long int.

Comment: It sounds like he realizes that; he's asking which one is clearer to read

Comment: What he's doing is violating the FAQ by asking a subjective question, which everyone else seems to get.